# Cannot Upload / Share android project on GitHub because of JetBrains

Tags: android, github, jetbrains-ide

Help! I have been trying for hours just to upload my Android project on GitHub. The problem is, every time I commit or push the project, I get redirected to a website called JetBrains IDE. And it asks me to "Authorize in GitHub" After that is a long time of loading without really redirecting me and uploading my Android files to github.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the stock Github built in Android Studio. For that you need to authorize you github account with your Android Studio IDE.